# Automatically compile LESS file on build server after every build

Tags: css, less, npm, nuget, build-server

I have a main.less file which in turn imports multiple other less files. What I want to achieve is to have main.less file compiled into main.css file after every build on the build server. I tried installing nodejs package as well as dotless nuget package for visual studio. Is there a way to somehow isolate nodejs package files to one folder in my project so compilation of less file can be run on a machine which does not have npm installed ? What are the options for achieving this? Can it be done with lessc package ?

Answer (score 1):

The command line lessc compiler do have a watch function, but the client side less.js compiler has one. You should use the following code in your HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="main.less" />
<script>less = { env: 'development'};</script>
<script src="less.js"></script>
<script>less.watch();</script>
```